# Are these modified harmonic series divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a new series is formed by taking every $n\mathrm{th}$ term (eg for $n=3$, the 3rd, 6th, 9th etc terms) of the harmonic series$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$$ is this new series divergent?

Comment: Yes it is. For example, for $n=3$, you have $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{12} +\cdots = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+ \cdots \right) = \infty
$$

Comment: Whoops, I should have seen that coming. If you make that comment an answer, I'll happily accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. For example, for $n=3$, you have
$$\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{6}+ \frac{1}{9}+ \frac{1}{12}+ \cdots = \frac{1}{3} \left( 
\frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \cdots\right) = \infty$$